Regressing time series of continuous proportions Y(invested in different buckets) against X (prices) variables
I am not sure of what model need to be applied in my case. So my goal is to model the below data.
I have the monthly deposits data from 2001 till 2024 for this analysis. Each customer can invest in different issue term like 1,2,3,4,5,6 … but for this analysis I tried to bucket these issue terms where 0-6 month is bucket A, 7-12 is bucket B, 13-18 is. bucket C, 18+ is bucket D. Now I have the data for allocation of deposits into these deposits across time into different buckets and I converted these deposit amounts into proportion between the buckets for a particular month.
Eg:

I also have the prices at which these deposits are issued at in another dataframe:

I need to build a model which should take the first dataframe as dependent data and the prices df as independent dataframe. If I feed in forecasted prices to the model it needs to give me allocation percentages for each bucket A, B, C, D that should sum up to 100%. I need to make sure that the regression accounts for correlations between balance proportions.
I read about how Dirichlet regression is used to model Time Series of Continuous Proportions but I am not able to understand how to regress it against prices. Any ideas of what models can fit in this scenario would help.

There are two approaches demonstrated here. Perhaps you can elaborate on what's giving you trouble?
